# memory leaks in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am using http-proxy to forward requests to specific ports

here is the code:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

options   = {
    hostnameOnly:true,
    router: {
        'appname.nodejs.mydomain.com':'127.0.0.1:8001',
        'otherapp.nodejs.mydomain.com':'127.0.0.1:8002'
    }
}
httpProxy.createServer(options).listen(80);
```

when i start it works just fine
but after online users got higher then 300 users, warning appeared

```
we have 338 users online.
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use      emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at Socket.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:175:15)
at Socket.EventEmitter.once (events.js:196:8)
at ClientRequest.HttpProxy.proxyRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/node-http-proxy/http-proxy.js:316:12)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:192:14)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
at ClientRequest.onSocket (http.js:1525:9)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
we have 339 users online.
```

could you please give me any suggestions about this issue?

Comment: that warning means there are 11 handlers added for an event, this can be by design in which you will want to increase the maxListeners. But to be sure you should track it down and check. Its not in the code supplied.

Comment: could you please be more detailed about tracking down and check? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not without seeing the code, if you know which emitter is causing the problem you can override the "on" method and debug there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NodeJS : How to debug "EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581978/nodejs-how-to-debug-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected-11-listeners-added)