# NodeJS : How to debug "EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added"

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, eventemitter

How can I debug my application which throw this error:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at Socket.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:160:15)
    at Socket.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:653:33)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.once (events.js:179:8)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:527:26)
```

I could not find the assumed leaking object for increasing listener limit by  `.setMaxListeners(0);`

**SOLUTION (from fardjad and jan salawa)**

With jan salawa's searches I found a working library ([longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn)) for increasing stack traces verbose. With fardjad's response I have found that we have to prototype `EventEmitter.addListener` **AND** `EventEmitter.on`.

With the solution I could get this new trace:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at EventEmitter.addListener.EventEmitter.on (xxx/main.js:44:15)
    at Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:653:33)
    at ServerResponse.assignSocket (http.js:1072:10)
    at parser.onIncoming (http.js:1979:11)
    at parserOnHeadersComplete (http.js:119:23)
    at socket.ondata (http.js:1912:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:510:27)
```

Comment: Check this out about agent.maxSockets http://weblog.bocoup.com/node-stress-test-analysis/ . Maybe that is a cause.

Comment: Tried with no success. I put `require("http").globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity;` at my main.js but nothing changed ... :( I also tried `ulimit -n 999999` command for open file limit and `-–nouse-idle-notification` for pausing real time garbage collector ...

Comment: This completely hangs up my node js server like an exception when running on local when i press control + C other processing start. I have tried setting maxListeners no use, What is it saying is it i have too many guys connected to same listeners or is it saying i have too many events

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It turns out that this is a bug in nodejs core, we are talking about this problem here : https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5108

**Solution for bugged http servers thats throw an `EventEmitter memory leak detected` and fill up the available memory / available CPU times :**

Revert to legacy version `v0.8.23`. (You can download and install/compile it from here : http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/04/08/node-v0-8-23-legacy/)

**UPDATE 2018 :** I see several feedbacks on this topic whereas the problem looks to be gone since years. Note that this response is **only for a leaking http server build with nodejs**. If you are in other scenario, please look the others responses on this thread and dont downgrade your version (as suggested on this response), you will waste your time.

Comment: I'll try and keep everyone posted on a more recent working version of node once they definitely fix this issue. I'm still getting problems with it.

Comment: why is it closed when the bug still is there in v0.10.24!?

Comment: @schlingel still in the v0.10.26

Comment: @schlingel I got it now in v0.10.31 !

Comment: I'm seeing this with v0.10.32

Comment: Present in v0.10.33 as well

Comment: 10.34 on and still have it

Comment: Confirm - it's in v0.10.33 - I just ran an old script developed back in the 0.8 days for the first time in ages, and BOOM... search brought me straight here.  Oh well, time to test it in "io.js" then, which I fear will work correctly (Are you reading this joyent!)

Comment: Sorry can't give you an honest answer to that, i didn't yet get chance to test it.

Comment: I see the same symptom in iojs (v1.3.0) and node (v0.12.2)

Comment: A solution seems to be here (not tested): https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/1136#issuecomment-128668154

Comment: and node v5.12.0 with npm 3.10.7

Comment: still happening with node v5.9.1 and npm v3.10.7

Comment: Node `v6.10.0`, npm: `4.6.1`  Still seeing this now :(

Comment: seeing on v8.11.3    (node:14) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 wakeup listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Answer (score 12):

For me it's looks like your event loop is blocked. This can happen if you are doing cpu intensive tasks in node.js event loop. You can use [child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to do intensive task.

You can check what is blocking node.js using [following methods](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/nodejs/1232z2xchk/how-to-detect-and-diagnose-event-loop-blocking):

1. [Measure computation time](https://github.com/CrabDude/trycatch/blob/master/lib/hook.js) of each call. Log if time is high so you know app is misbehaving.
2. Set up a log schedule so you know when something blocking loop

   ```
   function timeTick() {
       var startTime = (new Date().getTime());
       function onTick() {
           var interval = (new Date().getTime()) - startTime;
           if(interval > 5)
               console.log('timeTick(): WARNING: interval = ' + interval);
       }
      process.nextTick(onTick);
   }
   setInterval(timeTick, 1000);
   ```
3. Use [profile.](https://github.com/mape/node-profile)
4. Use [this](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) for logging and profiling. It's library used in **[Nodejitsu](http://readwrite.com/2011/06/03/nodejitsu-open-source-nodejs)**.

Comment: Yes, this problem is from an object with too many listeners added when intensive task. But i have to find witch object and increase the listener limit ! The question is how to find where the problem comes from ?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you are doing cpu intensive task. I've edited my post.

Comment: When intensive task (handling many connections) CPU does not go up than 20% of one core. But **after** the error occurs, the program start using 100% CPU and growing memory.

Comment: Ok can you show how are you handling these connections on server side?

Comment: I do not know if exporting only connection handling will help you. The problem may also comes from connection dependent i think ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26878/discussion-between-jan-salawa-and-anaelfavre)

Comment: Check out these topics how to deal with event loop blocking: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nodejs/GWD1ve9W5_k , http://grokbase.com/t/gg/nodejs/1232z2xchk/how-to-detect-and-diagnose-event-loop-blocking

Comment: I tried all you solutions : `1` Could not get it working for interesting measurments. `2` nothing here too, there already have 0 duration. `3` profile is too old and could not get it working with node v0.10. `4` I am trying to use it for low level debogging. (I am edditing my original post)

Answer (score 11):

This is exactly what happened to me. For me, I nested an event listener within another event listener accidentally.

Look at your code and make sure you DO NOT have an event listener block WITHIN another event listener block for example(unless you are doing it on purpose):

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
//code goes here

socket.on('close' , function() {
//code goes here
     });

   });
```

In the wrong example above, the socket.on ('close') listener should be OUTSIDE of the socket.on('data') block.

In my case when I received 5 data streams, the socket.on('close') listener is waiting for a close event to happen. When I close once, another 4th closing event would execute. This is clearly not what I wanted.  This is due to the nature of Node.js which is non-blocking. It 'remembers' events due to the callback function.

Comment: This was the cause root of my error too! I had ```somereaderstream.on("close", function(){ fstream.Reader({ 'path': basepath, 'type': 'Directory' }).on("end", function(){ ..... }); }); Thanks for pointing out!```

Answer (score 10):

Since node 6 you should use `node --trace-warnings`: https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_trace_warnings

Comment: Alternatively, there's https://github.com/niftylettuce/max-listeners-exceeded-warning

Answer (score 7):

This warning will be thrown if you register for a particular event of a same object more than 11 times.

Check if you are having 'on' call for particualr event in a function which you are calling frequently, this leads to registering for an event multiple times.

[This](https://medium.com/@jongleberry/understanding-node-jss-possible-eventemitter-leak-error-message-bc2ee68b24ea) link helped me to understand this.

Comment: It should be 'more than 10 times'.

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I have an app with play() and stop() methods. I have an EventEmitter to send a "stop signal" when stop() is called, which kills a process (video player). Problem was if I called play() 11 times: the process seems to have all the player processes registered as still open (even if they don't), so I needed to kill any process before starting a new one.

Answer (score 6):

> I tried to prototype the EventEmitter for adding log messages into
>   addListener but i could not get it working

To hook `addListener` you can do something like this:

```
// on the first line of your main script
var events = require("events"),
    EventEmitter = events.EventEmitter;

var originalAddListener = EventEmitter.prototype.addListener;
EventEmitter.prototype.addListener = function (type, listener) {
    if (this.listenerCount(this, type) >= 10) {
        // TODO: PLACE YOUR CODE FOR DEBUGGING HERE
    }
    originalAddListener.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: It does not work. The hook is called for some of my app listeners but not all listeners. Unfortunately, the `addListener` witch fire the error does not execute the hook (I tried to log all listerners removing condition).

Is this hook attaching on modules `events.EventEmitter.addListener` ? (maybe the problem comes from a "bad" module i am using ?)

Comment: The problem might be caused by a bad module, but `node.js` caches modules. Multiple attempts to `require` a module (normally) loads the module once. So if you install the hook on your main script, other modules should use the hooked `addListener`.

Comment: You're right, i tried to put your code in some modules and the result it the same : i got 20/30 listeners on differents objets at the beginning of my app and nothing when the error appear :(.

Comment: For really working we have to prototype `EventEmitter.addListener` AND `EventEmitter.on` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this when I was running my unit tests. My unit tests were repeatedly calling code that was calling:

```
process.on("uncaughtException", () => { ... });
```

I had to use dependency injection to inject a fake process object, which solved the problem.

main.js:

```
export function main(myProcess) {
    myProcess.on("uncaughtException", () => { ... });
}

if (require.main === module) { // to prevent this from executing when running unit tests
    main(process);
}
```

My unit tests would do:

```
const fakeProcess = jasmine.createSpy("process", ["on"]);
main(fakeProcess);
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem when testing **React** components using **mocha** and **enzyme**.

*I was able to solve my problem by explicitly unmounting components after I had finished testing them.*

The issue was that I was mounting components multiple times in my tests, which were then adding more listeners, until the number of listeners got to 11, and I got a warning.

I changed my test code by adding the **rendered.unmount()** line. This fixed the problem for me.

```
describe('<CircleArc />', () => {

    it('renders', function () {
        const rendered = mount(<CircleArc />);
        assert.ok(rendered.find('path'));
        rendered.unmount();
    });
}
```