# Mongoose - useDb(name) not allowing more than 10 concurrent request

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We are using mongoose to connect to MongoDB.Initially a pool of 100 connections is created and to connect to some other database using the mongoose method **useDb**

Below is the code snippet

```
var url = require("url");
var connectRoute = require('connect-route');
var connect = require('connect'),
    app = connect.createServer();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:10040/first', {server: {poolSize: 100}});

 conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 var MySchema = new Schema({
 user: String,
 pwd: String, roles: []
 },
 {strict: false}
 );
app.use(connectRoute(function (router){
    router.get('/get', function(req,res){
        var db2 = conn.useDb('second_DB');
        var data = db2.model('', MySchema, 'coll');
        data.update({name: "Janu"}, {$set: {"name": "test"}}, {upsert: true} , function (err, data,log) {
            //console.log(a.data.data );
            res.end(JSON.stringify(log.connectionId));
        });
    });
}));

app.listen(3000);
console.log('info','Connect server listening on port 3000 ' );
```

Even though Poolsize is set to 100 , when more than 10 concurrent requests are given throwing the warning as

**(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.**

MongoDB version - 2.6.4
Mongoose version - 3.8.12

can anyone help out on why this warning am getting ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581978/nodejs-how-to-debug-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected-11-listeners-added

Comment: It throws the warning when useDb method is used. Other than that for no other method it throws the warning.  When i comment the line     var db2 = conn.useDb('second_DB')   in the above code snippet am not getting the warning.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

The function `conn.useDb` create a new connection object and add an event listener on it. the size of the Poolsize does not affect that.

Your code effectively have an EventEmitter memoryleak. Each times the routes is called, a new object with an event listener is created and will never be deleted.

To fix your problem : cache the return value of conn.useDb.

If you have more than 10 databases, you can increase the limit of listener at the start of the application with :

```
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 15;
```

or with

```
emitter.setMaxListeners()
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to set [the `useCache` option](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-useDb) so that each `useDb` call won't create a new connection object.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following dbOptions while using `useDb()`

```
const useDbOptions = {
    //ensures connections to the same databases are cached
    useCache: true,
    //remove event listeners from the main connection
    noListener: true
}
    
conn.useDb('another_DB', useDbOptions);
```

Also make sure you manually delete all user models from each connection, after each request, using:

```
 conn.deleteModel(/.*/) // Delete all models on conn
```

This ensures excess memory is freed since each connection would otherwise maintain an internal list of all the models associated with a particular connection.

Refer: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9961 for a detailed info.

Answer (score 2):

use this option when useDb('name', {noListener:true} );

Comment: More information: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9961