# 'Write after end' error with Express, csvtojson and node-walk

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having issues sending JSON data from csv files with Express. It takes a folder of CSV files, loops through, converts it all to JSON and then spits it out at the end, but I'm getting the error `Error: write after end` as well as `(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.` after the first load. The error is only for when I try and hit the `/get` path, not the main index page.

I know it has something to do with read streams being closed or not closed, but I don't have enough knowledge to work out exactly what to do. Here's my code; any advice would be lovely. Ta!

Ps, technologies used are [Express](http://expressjs.com/), [Node-walk](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-walk) and [CSVtoJSON](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson).

### init.js

```
var _ = require('underscore')._;
var express = require('express');

var server = express();

server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/frontend/public/'));
server.listen(1234);

var getData = require('./src/getData.js');

server.get('/get', function (req, res) {
  getData.get(function (data) {
    res.send(data);
  })
});

server.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('./index.html');
});
```

#### getData.js

```
var walk      = require('walk');
var fs        = require('fs');
var _         = require('underscore')._;
var csvtojson = require('csvtojson').core.Converter;

var files = [];

var csvConverter = new csvtojson({constructResult: true});

exports.get = function (callback) {

  var csvWalker = walk.walk('./place-csvs-here', {followLinks: false});

  csvWalker.on('file', function (root, stat, next) {
    if (stat.name.match(/[A-Z]+?\-\d+?\.csv/gi)) {
      var filename = root + '/' + stat.name;
      files.push(fs.createReadStream(filename));
    }
    next();
  });

  csvWalker.on('end', function () {
    files.forEach(function (file) {
      file.pipe(csvConverter);
    });
  });

  csvConverter.on('end_parsed', function (data) {
    if (callback) {
      // Ensure rows are unique.
      data = _.uniq(data, function (x) {
        return JSON.stringify(x);
      });
      // Required fields.
      data = _.filter(data, function (x) {
        return (
           x['Date']    !== undefined
        && x['Balance'] !== undefined
        && x['Date']    !== 'Date'
        && x['Balance'] !== 'Balance'
          );
      });
      callback(data);
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: For the Memory leak warning see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581978/nodejs-how-to-debug-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected-11-listeners-added. It says its a bug in the core and to change the version.

Comment: Are you hitting the `/get` route 11 times and then getting the EventEmitter message on the 11th time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to re-use both `files` and the same csv converter instance for *all* requests. You're also trying to pipe many files at the same time to one parser instance. This is likely to confuse the parser.

Try this `getData.js` instead:

```
var walk      = require('walk');
var fs        = require('fs');
var _         = require('underscore')._;
var csvtojson = require('csvtojson').core.Converter;

exports.get = function (callback) {

  var csvWalker = walk.walk('./place-csvs-here', {followLinks: false});
  var files = [];
  var ret = [];

  csvWalker.on('file', function (root, stat, next) {
    if (stat.name.match(/[A-Z]+?\-\d+?\.csv/gi)) {
      var filename = root + '/' + stat.name;
      files.push(fs.createReadStream(filename));
    }
    next();
  });

  csvWalker.on('end', function () {
    var left = files.length;
    files.forEach(function (file) {
      var csvConverter = new csvtojson({constructResult: true});

      csvConverter.on('end_parsed', function (data) {
        if (callback) {
          if (--left === 0) {
            // Ensure rows are unique.
            ret = _.uniq(ret, function (x) {
              return JSON.stringify(x);
            });
            // Required fields.
            ret = _.filter(ret, function (x) {
              return (
                 x['Date']    !== undefined
              && x['Balance'] !== undefined
              && x['Date']    !== 'Date'
              && x['Balance'] !== 'Balance'
                );
            });
            callback(ret);
          } else
            ret = ret.concat(data);
        }
      });

      file.pipe(csvConverter);
    });
  });

}
```

This assumes that `data` passed in by the csv converter on 'end_parsed' is always an array. It combines the data from all files and *then* runs the filters on the data before executing the callback.

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you've done. Makes sense. Thanks! Another quick question though, would you know of any reason why `files` will contain, for example, 5 items and yet the final one in the list will never actually get parsed? It's always the final one alphabetically. Cheers

Comment: Hard to say, you might try just collecting filenames and deferring the creation of the readable file streams until inside the `forEach()`.