# Meteor HTTP requests causing memory leak warning

Tags: meteor, memory-leaks, httprequest

I have an application in which I make about 500 synchronous HTTP requests, where I save the description and images of websites. The code snippets are as follows, on the client side (with underscore.js):

```
_.each(websiteArray, function (website) {
  // websiteArray has about 500 urls
  Meteor.call("httpRequest", website);
});
```

On the server, using the http-more package, and CFS-store for images:

```
Meteor.methods({
  httpRequest: function (website) {
    this.unblock();
    var result = HTTP.get(website.url, {timeout: 30000});
    //save the largest image into CFS-store, description into another collection
  }
});
```

I encountered these errors calling the httpRequest method asynchronously, and I still get them when running it synchronously, but less often:

```
W20150824-17:18:06.385(-4)? (STDERR) (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
W20150824-17:18:06.389(-4)? (STDERR) Trace
W20150824-17:18:06.389(-4)? (STDERR)     at Request.addListener (events.js:160:15)
W20150824-17:18:06.389(-4)? (STDERR)     at Request.init (/home/rory/.meteor/packages/http/.1.1.0.43csqa++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:618:8)
W20150824-17:18:06.389(-4)? (STDERR)     at Request.onRequestResponse (/home/rory/.meteor/packages/http/.1.1.0.43csqa++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1127:10)
W20150824-17:18:06.389(-4)? (STDERR)     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
W20150824-17:18:06.389(-4)? (STDERR)     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1693:21)
W20150824-17:18:06.390(-4)? (STDERR)     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23)
W20150824-17:18:06.390(-4)? (STDERR)     at CleartextStream.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1588:20)
W20150824-17:18:06.390(-4)? (STDERR)     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:514:12)
W20150824-17:18:06.390(-4)? (STDERR)     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:341:10)
W20150824-17:18:06.390(-4)? (STDERR)     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:369:25) 
W20150824-17:18:06.469(-4)? (STDERR) (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
W20150824-17:18:06.471(-4)? (STDERR) Trace
W20150824-17:18:06.471(-4)? (STDERR)     at Request.addListener (events.js:160:15)
W20150824-17:18:06.471(-4)? (STDERR)     at Request.start (/home/rory/.meteor/packages/http/.1.1.0.43csqa++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:937:8)
W20150824-17:18:06.472(-4)? (STDERR)     at Request.end (/home/rory/.meteor/packages/http/.1.1.0.43csqa++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1635:10)
W20150824-17:18:06.472(-4)? (STDERR)     at end (/home/rory/.meteor/packages/http/.1.1.0.43csqa++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:676:14)
W20150824-17:18:06.472(-4)? (STDERR)     at Object._onImmediate (/home/rory/.meteor/packages/http/.1.1.0.43csqa++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:690:7)
W20150824-17:18:06.472(-4)? (STDERR)     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:354:15)
```

Are these warnings merely warnings? I have not been able to find the proper procedure for sending many HTTP requests while not entirely hogging the server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581978/nodejs-how-to-debug-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected-11-listeners-added