# Node.js How to setMaxListeners()

Tags: node.js

I never used the node.js before. But followd the steps from [here](https://github.com/dergachev/solr-security-proxy) for solr security proxy. Everything is working fine but its giving me this warning. I know i have to set max listener, but don't know how and where i do. Kindly help me please.

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at addListener (events.js:160:15)
    at /home/abc/node_modules/solr-security-proxy/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/node-http-proxy/routing-proxy.js:63:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/abc/node_modules/solr-security-proxy/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/node-http-proxy/routing-proxy.js:62:33)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
    at addListener (events.js:138:10)
    at Array.0 (/home/abc/node_modules/solr-security-proxy/solr-security-proxy.js:69:13)
    at Server.handler (/home/abc/node_modules/solr-security-proxy/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/node-http-proxy.js:175:40)
    at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2164:12)
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at addListener (events.js:160:15)
    at Array.0 (/home/abc/node_modules/solr-security-proxy/solr-security-proxy.js:69:13)
    at Server.handler (/home/abc/node_modules/solr-security-proxy/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/node-http-proxy.js:175:40)
    at Server.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2164:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:152:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:2022:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this problem because I was trying to run more than 10 asynchronous tasks, so I really did need more than 10 event listeners.  But the actual event listener code was in a library/module I was using, so I couldn't use `setMaxListeners()` as I didn't have access to the object.  In the end, overriding the global value once at the start of the program worked for me:

```
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

You call [`setMaxListeners`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n) on the same object on which you are calling [`addListener`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_addlistener_eventname_listener) (or [`on`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener)), which will be an [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter).

However, if you actually do have an emitter memory leak (rather than just happening to need 11 listeners and no more), then you need to fix that problem at its source - raising the limit won't help you.

See: [How to debug “EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15581978/476716)